# Rounding in PHP and Java Different Outputs

Tags: java, php, math, integer, rounding

I want to produce the same output in JAVA as in PHP, however when dividing two integers, certain numbers produce different outputs in both.

JAVA Code:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number1 = 5834985;
        int number2 = 9;

        System.out.println(number1 / number2);
    }
}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$number1 = 5834985;
$number2 = 9;
$a = $number1 / $number2;

echo round($a, 0);
?>
```

The JAVA code outputs: **648331**

The PHP code outputs:  **648332**

However if you change the second number to an 8 they output:

The JAVA code outputs: **729373**

The PHP code outputs:  **729373**

**How would you be able to produce the same output on both consistently if the second number is constantly changing?**

Comment: Codes are not equivalent - PHP version uses rounding, while JAVA version just does integer division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [floor](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/func_math_floor.asp) function as below

```
<?php
    $number1 = 5834985;
    $number2 = 8;
    $a = $number1 / $number2;

    echo floor($a);
?>
```

Output:

> 648331

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing 2 integers in java, and it will only return the whole number as a result.

try using `float` or `double`